# Sharepoint Online Powershell app change password expiration with insufficient privileges

Tags: sharepoint, passwords

How can I change the password of a Sharepoint Online app with Powershell
I am using this

```
$result = Add-MgServicePrincipalPassword -ServicePrincipalId $appPrincipal.Id -BodyParameter $params
```

As result I get this:
Add-MgServicePrincipalPassword : Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
Status: 403 (Forbidden)
ErrorCode: Authorization_RequestDenied

I do not know which privilege has to be set.
Thanks for Your answers.